# I would like to analyze the data using R and Python. How to handle 10 millions records of data?

Tags: r, predictive-models, python, database

I would like to analyze the data using R and Python, and I am unable to open text file due to huge number of records. Is there any free database software to install in PC and load the data into it and then analyze using Python and R.

Answer (score 3):

One R package will change your life: `data.table`.